# two decorators on one function,the back one not work as expected?

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

I have two decorators on one function.
Each decorator adds an attribute to the function, but the first decorator's attribute is not passed to the function after it has been initiated.

Why does `f3.calls` remain 0 in the following code?

```
def memorize(fn):
    result_list3 = {}

    @wraps(fn)
    def wrapper(n):
        wrapper.calls2 += 1
        print("memorize calls2", wrapper.calls2)
        found = result_list3.get(n)
        if found is not None:
            result = found
        else:
            result = fn(n)
            result_list3.update({n: result})
            # print(result_list3)
        return result

    wrapper.calls2 = 0
    return wrapper


def countt(fn):
    @wraps(fn)
    def wrapper(n):
        wrapper.calls += 1
        print("countt calls", wrapper.calls)
        result = fn(n)
        return result

    wrapper.calls = 0
    return wrapper


@memorize
@countt
def f3(n):
    if n < 3:
        return n
    else:
        result = f3(n - 1) + 2 * f3(n - 2) + 3 * f3(n - 3)
        return result


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(f3(10))
    print(f3.calls)  # 0
    print(f3.calls2)  # 25
```

here is the log:

```
memorize calls2 1
countt calls 1
memorize calls2 2
countt calls 2
memorize calls2 3
countt calls 3
memorize calls2 4
countt calls 4
memorize calls2 5
countt calls 5
memorize calls2 6
countt calls 6
memorize calls2 7
countt calls 7
memorize calls2 8
countt calls 8
memorize calls2 9
countt calls 9
memorize calls2 10
countt calls 10
memorize calls2 11
countt calls 11
memorize calls2 12
memorize calls2 13
memorize calls2 14
memorize calls2 15
memorize calls2 16
memorize calls2 17
memorize calls2 18
memorize calls2 19
memorize calls2 20
memorize calls2 21
memorize calls2 22
memorize calls2 23
memorize calls2 24
memorize calls2 25
1892
0
25
```

Answer (score 1):

Each decorator assigns a new function `wrapper` to the name `f3`, which means there are 3 different functions being called: the original `f3`, the `wrapper` returned from `countt`, and the `wrapper` returned from `memorize`. In your last lines, `print(f3...)` refers to the `wrapper` from `memorize`. But inside the `wrapper` in `countt`, `wrapper.calls += 1` refers to that `wrapper` from `countt` and not the one from `memorize`. So you don't see the effect of `wrapper.calls += 1` because you're looking at the wrong function object. However if you check `f3.__wrapped__.calls` you will see the correct value (11).

The reason that the final `f3` (the `wrapper` from `memorize`) even has a `calls` attribute at all is because `@wraps` in `memorize` copies that attribute from the `wrapper` from `countt` to the `wrapper` from `memorize`.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at the wrong `calls` attribute. Here is what happens:

- `countt` produces a `wrapper()` function to replace the decorated function. Let's call this `countt.<local>.wrapper()` (even though `functools.wraps()` sets the `__name__` attribute to `f3`). This wraps the original function `fn`, and `functools.wraps()` copies all function attributes over to `countt.<local>.wrapper()`. You added a `calls` attribute to `countt.<local>.wrapper()`, so lets call that `countt.<local>.wrapper.calls`.
- `memorize` produces a `wrapper()` function to replace the decorated function `fn`. Let's call this `memorize.<local>.wrapper()`. This wraps the passed in function `fn`, which here is `countt.<local>.wrapper()`. `functools.wraps()` copies all function attributes over to `memorize.<local>.wrapper()`, *including `countt.<local>.wrapper.calls`*, becoming `memorize.<local>.wrapper.calls`, set to `0`. You added a `calls2` attribute to `memorize.<local>.wrapper()`, so lets call that `memorize.<local>.wrapper.calls2`.

You then run the code. `countt.<local>.wrapper()` keeps updating `countt.<local>.wrapper.calls`. Note that `memorize.<local>.wrapper.calls` is *never altered here*, that's a *different, independent attribute*.

You then print `f3.calls` and `f3.calls2`. `f3.calls` is 0, because that's really `memorize.<local>.wrapper.calls`, not `countt.<local>.wrapper.calls`.

If you are running Python 3.2 or newer, you can reach the wrapped function with the `__wrapped__` attribute; `f3.__wrapped__` here is `countt.<local>.wrapper()`, so you can see the *correct* `calls` attribute with:

```
print(f3.__wrapped__.calls)
```